# Bootstrap + Flexslider: Loading Flexslider within hidden element causes jQuery to be unresponsive

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

I have a login page which loads just fine when above 767px wide and crashes the browser below that width. It only crashes when loading below that width, I can load at desktop width then size down just fine.

I have one div with `.visible-desktop` that contains the desktop login and superfluous stuff and another with `.hidden-desktop` containing only the mobile login. An image in the superfluous stuff is currently 404'ing. I'll fix it but it sure shouldn't be crashing the browser.

In the server console, the asset previous to the 404 asset loads and nothing else happens. In the browser, the page becomes unresponsive and crashes. Chrome just crashs and FF says

```
A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding. You can stop the script now, or you can continue to see if the script will complete.

Script: http://ccdev:3333/assets/jquery.js?body=1:6265
```

**Update:**
Using firebug and inserting a breakpoint on line 6348 in jquery v1.8.2 and stepping through it seems it's stuck incrementing something called `elems`. On one step the value will be something like `"<li><a>177085</a></li>"`, on the next it will be `"<li><a>177086</a></li>"` and it never leaves that line. The line in question is

```
div.parentNode.removeChild( div );
```

Comment: I haven't reproduced the error in a minimal use case yet http://jsfiddle.net/archonic/qWLGn/5/

Comment: I've narrowed it down to a conflict between bootstrap and flexslider. If flexslider elements aren't a part of the DOM, it doesn't initialize. Then when bootstrap tries to remove flexslider's parent element, there's an infinite loop trying to remove the flexslider navigation links.

Comment: Turns out the dead linked image had nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be an issue with Woothemes flexslider. jQuery can not remove items hidden by bootstrap. If loading the page at a width where flexslider is hidden, jquery has an infinite loop which will cause the browser to hang and crash.

I found the fix [here](https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider/issues/463). Just initialize flexslider with `minItems: 1`. Which should really be the default!