# Chrome crashing on page load

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, twig, silex

I'm developing a site on Silex + Twig. Most of the time, everything looks great, but once in a while, without any JS errors, chrome will crash the page just after loading the content.
It only happens on some computers, what made me think that it might be a memory problem.
Unfortunately, I cannot provide any code, mostly because I would have to provide the whole source code, since I cannot pinpoint the problem.

Have any of you ever had problems like this? If so, how did you solve it? Where should I look first? Please, if you can, send me some light on this matter.

EDIT: On the beginning of the project, this started happening A LOT, like 3 out of 4 refreshes, so we switched from Symfony to Silex... In my machine, it solved the problem, but in some others, it still happens, in minor frequency.

Comment: I doubt anyone will be able to help you without code, could be an infinite code loop

Comment: Well, I don't expect a solution, but at least some guidance from someone who might have gone through that already... Maybe is a known issue that I'm not aware of... As for infinite code loop, silex is a bitch about the code, so I don't think it would have gone unoticed, but I'll check anyway...

Comment: @DominicTobias Turns out you were right... Flexslider was causing Jquery to enter an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

I got it...

It was a problem with the flexslider plugin.
In this question there's the explanation and solution:
[Bootstrap + Flexslider: Loading Flexslider within hidden element causes jQuery to be unresponsive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15008675/bootstrap-flexslider-loading-flexslider-within-hidden-element-causes-jquery-t)

Thanks anyway... :D